# matlab image blurring using fspecial

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a matlab program for image blurring. I am required to use `fspecial('average')` and `conv2` function. So far I have written the following code:

```
x=imread('ghoul.jpg');
subplot(211),imshow(x)
h=fspecial('average');
y=conv2(double(x),double(h));
subplot(212),imshow(y)
```

size of `x` is 250X250 uint8

The problem with the code is that it displays the original image fine but the image is only blurred at the bottom and white in the remaining area.
So far I have guessed that I haven't specified the size in `h`. But I am having problem in how to define the size in `h`. Whether it should be the size of `x` or not. It would be helpful if someone can just tell me how to write the size or another tip. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Default size 3x3 filter should be good for averaging. Either your original image is white or the filtered results might need re-scaling to get its values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Try using `imshow(y,[])`. The problem is likely that when `imshow` is used on an array of type `double`, the expected range is between `0.0` and `1.0`. The `[]` will automatically rescale the intensity values so the image displays properly.

Comment: @eigenchris Thank you very much. The empty brackets solved the issue.

Comment: @eigenchris Consider creating an answer for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the matlab code is that it was using imshow on double data type which caused the image intensity value to distort (barely visible or invisible in certain areas of the image). The filtered image needed rescaling of intensity values and as @eigenchris pointed out using: 
  imshow(y,[])
readjusted the image intensity values and the image was blurred perfectly.
side note: The size of the filter didn't had any effect on image distortion. (size is just used as a measure to how much you want to blur the image)